# How to use something other than "Index" as the default controller view in ASP.NET Core MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.Net MVC/Razor app.  The default view is always assumed to be Index.html, and I would like to know where that is set and whether that can be changed.  I do not like having dozens of files all named Index.cshtml, and would prefer my default files to be named something else.

Is is possible to change this default?  I know that I can just set a different view path when Index is called in the controller, but would like something less manual.

Answer (score 1):

Just change your route template:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{               
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=OtherPage}/{id?}"); 
});
```

Comment: would this mean that http://localhost/foo would route to the "OtherPage" method in the "Home" controlller?

Comment: When you set route template with specific controller name and action like:"OtherPage" method in HomeController.The default url `https://localhost:44378`(44378 is port number) will route to it.

Comment: Hi @DanielWilliams,any update?Did my answer help you resolve your issue?

Comment: Thanks.  I did not take this approach, but rather had the Index method point to a different view instead.  But it is helpful to know I could do it this way.